# Find what a Infinite product number approaches

Tags: fractions, infinite-product

Find what the following number approaches:
$$\frac{6}{5}\times\frac{26}{25}\times\frac{626}{625}\times\frac{390626}{390625}\times...$$

---

What I found is that each fraction can be simplified as:$$1+\frac{1}{5^n}$$
Where $n$ is $1,2,4,8$ and so on (instead of $1,2,3,4,\ldots$)

What should I do next?

**Note: Please use junior high school math if possible**

Comment: @Damien Thanks for the notice.

Comment: or do u mean the reciprocal of what you have written?

Comment: *Hint*: Notice that the product is in fact $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty 5^{-i} $$ you can observe it by just expand the product. Take one term in each product and you will see that.

Comment: The same idea https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622321/399263

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{5^1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^8}\right)\cdots$$

$$=\left(1+\frac{1}{5^1}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^8}\right)\cdots$$

$$=\left(1+\frac{1}{5^1}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{5^5}+\frac{1}{5^6}+\frac{1}{5^7}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^8}\right)\cdots$$

$$=1+\frac{1}{5^1}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{5^5}+\frac{1}{5^6}+\frac{1}{5^7}+\frac{1}{5^8}+\cdots$$

$$= \frac{5}{5-1} \\= 1+\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 4):

Put $x=\frac{1}{5}$ then we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)..(1+x^{2^n})$$ now multiply $1-x$ in numerator and denominator and use $(1-x^{2^k})(1+x^{2^k})=1-x^{2^{k+1}}$ repeatedly and see the magic!

Comment: It's a magic [telescoping product](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/TelescopingSums.shtml). ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Indeed it is,:)