# $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=x+1$. What is this formula called? Is it even useful?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was playing around with some equations and I got to this formula:

$$
\prod\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=x+1 
$$

I checked it with particular values and it holds true when x is a positive integer.

I never saw this formula before. Is it just a useless formula? If not, does it have a name?

Comment: Not holding true for $x=1,2,3...$. Perhaps it should be $x+1$ on the RHS. Not very difficult to see why: $1+1/n=(n+1)/n$

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad. Youre right, its x+1

Comment: It's an example of a [telescoping product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) (scroll down a bit to see the bit about telescoping product). Not sure about any particular name, though.

Comment: No name for this formula, it's just the textbook example of a telescoping product

Comment: Telescoping sums where $b_k = a_{k+1}-a_k$ so $b_0 +b_1 + b_2 + ..... + b_n = (-a_0 + a_1) + (-a_1 + a_2) + (-a_2 + a_3) + ..... + (-a_{n-1}+a_n) + (-a_n + a_{n+1}) = -a_0 + a_{n+1} = a_{n+1} - a_0$ are much more common.  But no reason you can't have a "telescoping" serially cancelling product.  This are called "telescoping" because... the fold up and collapse upon themselves like a telescope does.  (It helps if you've ever seen a telescope of tubes within tubes so that it collapses into a tiny case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting observation. To see what's going on it helps to rewrite $(1 + 1/n)$ as $\frac{n+1}{n}$. Then for example if $x = 4$ we have
$$
\Pi_{n=1}^4 (1 + \frac1n) = \frac21 \cdot \frac32 \cdot \frac 43 \cdot \frac54 = 5.
$$
Everything cancels out except for the numerator in the final term in the product.

I'm not aware of any name for this formula.

Comment: Oh yeah, I understand it better now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ross They aren't common, but here's another telescoping product question from a few weeks ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4001694/207316