# Proving $\prod_{k=1}^{N} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) = \frac{1}{1+N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

It's been a long time since I've done this sort of thing, so can't remember how to solve this or the specific key terms to look it up and check for duplicate answers.

$$\prod_{k=1}^{N} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) = \frac{1}{1+N}$$

What's this sort of thing called and what method is used to prove it?

Comment: $1-\dfrac1{k+1}=\dfrac k{k+1}$ and then it [telescopes](https://brilliant.org/wiki/telescoping-series-product/)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031376/prod-limits-n-1x-left1-frac1n-right-x1-what-is-this-formula-cal) is a similar question

Comment: Thanks, got it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=x+1$. What is this formula called? Is it even useful?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031376/prod-limits-n-1x-left1-frac1n-right-x1-what-is-this-formula-cal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [telescoping product](https://brilliant.org/wiki/telescoping-series-product/).  All terms completely cancel except for the first and last.

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{N}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{N}\left( \frac{k}{k+1}\right) $$

$$  =\frac1{ {2}}\cdot\frac{ {2}}{ {3}}\cdot\frac{ {3}}{ {4}}\cdot\frac{ {4}}{ {5}}\cdots\frac { {k}}{ {k+1}}\cdots\frac{{ {N-1}}}{ {N}}\frac { {N}}{N+1}$$

$$\require{cancel}  =\frac1{\cancel{2}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{2}}{\cancel{3}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{3}}{\cancel{4}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{4}}{\cancel{5}}\cdots\frac {\cancel{k}}{\cancel{k+1}}\cdots\frac{{\cancel{N-1}}}{\cancel{N}}\frac {\cancel{N}}{N+1}$$

$$= \frac{1}{N+1}=\frac{1}{1+N}$$