# Calculate $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n(2^m n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

As title, to calculate $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n(2^m n+1)}$$

I tried to calculate $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^m n+1}$$
but to no avail.

Then, as the addend looks similar to
$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{x^n}n=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$
, I tried:
$$\ln(1-x) = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}n=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$
So,
$$\frac{1}{2x} \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}=1+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{5}+\cdots$$
Again,
$$\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2x} \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} + \frac{1}{2xi} \ln\frac{1+xi}{1-xi}\right) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n-2}}{2n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}$$

$$=1+\frac{x^4}{5}+\frac{x^8}{9}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{4n}}{4n+1}$$
but still to no avail....

Comment: Perhaps you could do partial fraction decomposition on $1/n(2^m n + 1)$ and evaluate the sum using the [digamma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_representation) function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n(2^m n+1)}
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\int_0^1 x^{2^m n}\,dx
\\&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\int_0^1\log(1+x^{2^m})\,dx
\\&=-\int_0^1\log(1-x)\,dx=1.
\end{align}
The second equality (i.e., the ability to move the summation over $n$ under the integral) is justified by the uniform convergence of the power series, thanks to [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). The third equality follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622321).

Comment: super! now i learn how to handle $2^m n+1$.